# Custom model instance ordering via Meta?

Tags: wagtail

I am not able to get a custom default ordering for my page model instances. They are always sorted by their `pk`, ascending.

This results in unintuitive dropdowns, choosers (e.g. `CheckboxSelectMultiple`) etc.; especially when there are a lot of items/instances.

Use case: An `AuthorPage` and a `PublicationPage` model:

```
class AuthorPage(Page):
    first_name = CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['last_name', 'first_name']

class ArticlePage(Page):
    authors = ParentalManyToManyField('AuthorPage',)
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('authors', widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple),
    ]
```

I like my `CheckboxSelectMultiple` to honor the Meta ordering of the related model, here `AuthorPage` and display an alphabetically ordered list of authors. But, instead, I get this list ordered by the `pk` of the author instances. It seems the `ordering` on the `AuthorPage` class is not evaluated/used.

The same (unwanted) ordering appears in dropdown lists of authors and in the python shell when inspecting the default `AuthorPage` queryset (`AuthorPage.objects.all()`).

How do get wagtail to order the instances of my page model by a custom criteria (not the `pk`)?

---

Setup:

- Django  2.0.8
- wagtail  2.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is to extend and change the default `PageManager` for this model class (again: thanks @allcaps):

```
class ProfilePageManager(PageManager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().order_by('last_name', 'first_name')

class ProfilePage(Page):
    objects = ProfilePageManager()
```

The default page manager returns a queryset with `order_by('path')` [1], so I've changed this to return a queryset ordered by my custom criteria: `order_by('last_name', 'first_name')`.

Now widgets (eg. `CheckboxSelectMultiple`), dropdowns etc. receive this ordered queryset as options/choices throughout the whole site with no need to modify their existing instantiation.

[1] https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/core/models.py#L191

Answer (score 1):

You assumption that Wagtail page order is by pk is wrong. Wagtail orders the pages by path (Wagtail uses django-treebeard). This enables user defined ordering. First click the order symbol (first column), then drag and drop the pages.

[image: Wagtail Page list ordering]

This is what the docs say:

> Page-derived models *cannot* be given a default ordering by using the standard Django approach of adding an ordering attribute to the internal Meta class.
>
> This is because Page enforces ordering QuerySets by path. Instead, you must apply the ordering explicitly when constructing a QuerySet:

```
news_items = NewsItemPage.objects.live().order_by('-publication_date')
```

Docs: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.3/topics/pages.html#page-queryset-ordering

Can you try to define the choices - and thereby the ordering - yourself? Something like this might work:

```
FieldPanel(
    'authors', 
    widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple(
        choices=ProfilePage.objects.all().order_by('title').values_list('pk', 'title')
    )
),
```

Comment: Dear @allcaps, thanks a lot. I kind of missed that part of the documentation. As I didn't get the custom choices attribute on the widget to work properly, I use now  a custom page manager with the desired ordering and set this manager as the default manager for the model (in my case for ``AuthorPage``).

Comment: You might add your model manager as an answer, it will help others. Comments are not persistent on SO.